# Id path on capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a problem.

I'm trying to use capybara to do integration tests, but I can not get the id on my page for it to make the visit when I test the context "edit new tarefa". I'm using devise, so I create the user at the beginning of the code.

Below is the code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Tarefas", :type => :feature do
  feature "New Tarefa" do
    background do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    end

    context "create new tarefa" do
      it "preenchendo os campos" do
        visit '/tarefas/new'
        within("#new_tarefa") do
          fill_in 'tarefa_titulo', with: 'user@example.com'
          fill_in 'tarefa_descricao', with: 'password'
          fill_in 'tarefa_data', with: '18/06/1990 20:00'
        end
        click_button 'submit'
        expect(page).to have_content 'Mostra a tarefa selecionada'
      end
    end

    context "edit new tarefa" do
      it "alterando os campos" do
        visit "tarefas/#{Tarefa.last.id}/edit"
        within("#new_tarefa") do
          fill_in 'tarefa_titulo', with: 'user@exa12mple.com'
          fill_in 'tarefa_descricao', with: 'passw213ord'
          fill_in 'tarefa_data', with: '18/06/1990 21:00'
        end
        click_button 'submit'
        expect(page).to have_content 'Mostra a tarefa selecionada'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on the `tarefa` you have created in "create new tarefa" to be available in you next spec as:

- It won't work since the ordering is random.
- It would create a coupling where one spec relies on the outcome of another.

Instead you want to use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to clean out the DB after each spec and use `let` and `let!` to setup the requirements for each spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

# You can use `feature` as a top level block. 
# No need to nest it in descibe.
RSpec.feature "New Tarefa" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:tarefa) { FactoryGirl.create(:tarefa) }

  background do
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end

  context "create new tarefa" do
    it "preenchendo os campos" do
      visit '/tarefas/new'
      within("#new_tarefa") do
        fill_in 'tarefa_titulo', with: 'user@example.com'
        fill_in 'tarefa_descricao', with: 'password'
        fill_in 'tarefa_data', with: '18/06/1990 20:00'
      end
      click_button 'submit'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Mostra a tarefa selecionada'
    end
  end

  context "edit new tarefa" do
    it "alterando os campos" do
      # tarefa is created when you reference it.
      visit "tarefas/#{tarefa.to_param}/edit"
      within("#new_tarefa") do
        fill_in 'tarefa_titulo', with: 'user@exa12mple.com'
        fill_in 'tarefa_descricao', with: 'passw213ord'
        fill_in 'tarefa_data', with: '18/06/1990 21:00'
      end
      click_button 'submit'
      expect(page).to have_content 'Mostra a tarefa selecionada'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Additionally you should use the actual labels as seen by the user in feature specs - avoid using CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have an error message:

Failure / Error: <% = form_for @ f | %>
     
      ActionView :: Template :: Error:
        First argument in form can not contain nil or be empty

Comment: You need to learn how to do some basic problem solving on your own. I'm not here to hand hold you.